# Count number of keys in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

For simple localstorage we use localstorage.length. But I'm using a plugin [localStorageDB](https://github.com/knadh/localStorageDB) which has JSON output like the one shown below. I want to count "cart" items ('data' -> 'cart').

Also localstorage.length gives an output of 1 whenever I add Products. The products are however added inside the 'data'->'cart'.

```
{
"tables": {
    "cart": {
        "fields": [
            "ID",
            "item",
            "quantity",
            "cost"
        ],
        "auto_increment": 3
    }
},
"data": {
    "cart": {
        "1": {
            "ID": 1,
            "item": "Nature Fresh Atta Chakki Fresh 10 kg",
            "quantity": "1",
            "cost": "252"
        },
        "2": {
            "ID": 2,
            "item": "Fortune Refined Oil Soya Bean 1 Lt",
            "quantity": "1",
            "cost": "85"
        }
    }
}}
```

More Info  :
I obtained the serialized output using 'cart.serialize()'plugin syntax
[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/0i9ixCX.png)

Comment: Can you show the actual code where you try to get the count?

Comment: @derape I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
syntax: Object.keys(obj).length);


var data = {
        "tables": {
            "cart": {
                "fields": [
                    "ID",
                    "item",
                    "quantity",
                    "cost"
                ],
                "auto_increment": 3
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "cart": {
                "1": {
                    "ID": 1,
                    "item": "Nature Fresh Atta Chakki Fresh 10 kg",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "cost": "252"
                },
                "2": {
                    "ID": 2,
                    "item": "Fortune Refined Oil Soya Bean 1 Lt",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "cost": "85"
                }
            }
        }
    }

console.log(Object.keys(data['data']['cart']).length);
```

Comment: It says ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: data is variable in which json is stored Check the answer now

Comment: I've added a Firebug screenshot. Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorageDB` plugin has the built in method `rowCount()` for counting entries in a table.

So, something like this should work: `yourLib.rowCount('cart')`